# Model Performance is Fluctuating

Tags: deep-learning, cnn, accuracy

I am training a 3D u-net model for 3D medical images. My training data has 800 images, the validation data has 200, and test data has 200 images. when I try to fit the model, there is a fluctuation in the training and validation accuracy. Does that mean that my model is not learned properly?

[image: Model Performance]